# Pb installing Date::Manip with cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

I am struggling for one day installing date: with cpan (I am using os x). I always get this message

```
Warning: prerequisite Test::Inter 0 not found.
Bareword found where operator expected at ./Makefile.PL line 1, near "30 mtime"
    (Missing operator before mtime?)
Number found where operator expected at ./Makefile.PL line 2, near "30"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./Makefile.PL line 2, near "30 atime"
    (Missing operator before atime?)
Number found where operator expected at ./Makefile.PL line 3, near "30"
    (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Bareword found where operator expected at ./Makefile.PL line 3, near "30 ctime"
    (Missing operator before ctime?)
ERROR from evaluation of /Users/mehdibenchoufi/.cpan/build/SBECK-QEN4kY/Date-Manip-6.36/Makefile.PL: ERROR from evaluation of /Users/mehdibenchoufi/.cpan/build/SBECK-QEN4kY/Date-Manip-6.36/PaxHeaders.11917/Makefile.PL: syntax error at ./Makefile.PL line 1, near "30 mtime"
Warning: No success on command[/opt/local/bin/perl5.12 Makefile.PL]
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  SBECK/Date-Manip-6.36.tar.gz
  /opt/local/bin/perl5.12 Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
 SBECK/Date-Manip-6.36.tar.gz                 : writemakefile NO '/opt/local/bin/perl5.12 Makefile.PL' returned status 65280
```

Does anyone knows how to debug ?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue and these steps worked for me:

```
> sudo cpan
cpan[1]> install CPAN
cpan[2]> exit
> sudo rm -rf ~/.cpan/build/SBECK-*
> sudo cpan Date::Manip
```

Comment: could you please explain the steps you did and why they helped?

Comment: Thanks Gui!  This worked for me.  These commands update CPAN to the newest version, remove the old build files and then attempt to install the package again.  I didn't have to remove the ./cpan/build/... directory.  It just worked!

Comment: This worked because of PAX-headers in the tarball, and the newer version of the CPAN client which handles this. See also https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1184194

Answer (score 0):

Start by installing YAML.pm and Test::Iter.pm

But. You might not want to mess with the system perl on OS X.

You might want to give serious consideration to using perlbrew to manage a local install of perl wiith its own set of modules, separate form the system install.